# Audio - Compute samples for a given length with a start and end tempo

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, music-theory

I'm working on some audio analysis code and I'm currently trying to determine the number of audio samples that would be needed in a segment of audio in which the tempo changes linearly. I know start tempo, end tempo, and the length of time which the change occurs for. Below I'll state the problem in the simplest form possible (removing all real-world units):

---

Suppose the relationship $s = \frac{l}{t}$, where

*s* is a number of audio samples

*l* is a length of time

*t* is a tempo.

Derive a formula to compute samples *s* for any given *l*, *t<sub>start</sub>* and *t<sub>end</sub>*, where tempo *t* varies through *l* with a *linear* *f(x)* such that:

*t<sub>start</sub>* = *f(0)*, *t<sub>end</sub>* = *f(l)*.

---

So for example, I could put the following conditions into the formula to find the number of audio samples needed for a segment of length 100 (seconds, or whatever unit) where tempo increases from 30 to 150 (BPM, or whatever unit).

*t<sub>start</sub>* = *30*, *t<sub>end</sub>* = *150*, *l* = *100*

And in that case since I'm only interested in a linear tempo change, we'd have

$f(x) = t_{start}+ \frac{t_{end} - t_{start}}{l}x = 30 + 1.2 x$

---

Now where I'm hung up is the fact that we have tempo and sample count having an inverse relationship. The naive method I tried at first of simply averaging *t<sub>start</sub>* and *t<sub>end</sub>* through the window didn't work as a result (as sample count is actually not changing linearly throughout that time). I then thought that perhaps I'd have to integrate this formula with respect to *t* (which gives $l \ln t$) but then I got hung up on how to apply that to find the final sample count.

I'm probably just a few steps away here. Any push in the right direction would be great!

(*Edit: it may be more prudent to call the variable "l" a number of 'beats' or 'bars', to confer the point that it is a fixed quantity and does not vary as tempo changes the actual length in time the segment would take to change by affecting sample count.*)

Comment: I added the music theory tag, but I’m not sure if that’s really relevant

Comment: For me, something got simplified away when you mathematized the problem. Is the issue that the samples don’t have a uniform length? Like, if samples with tempos 30 and 31 play back to back, the higher tempo plays for less time?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think so. Samples don't vary in length of course as there will be some samples per second associated with them in playback (e.g. 44100) and the formula would compute the _quantity_ that play. But yes, a lower _quantity_ would play for the same beat duration at a faster tempo, as you'd expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer here. Luckily the solution wasn't so straightforward as just multiplying by the right thing in the right place, so I feel a bit justified in getting stumped for a while!

So, the relationship

$s = \frac{l}{t}$

gives a *total* sample count for a given *l* and *t*. This is useful when *l* and *t* are *constants*, because then we can just directly compute *s*. It is *less* useful if one of them varies, as we have for *t*.

In this case, it is more useful to compute a step function that gives the number of samples per an arbitrary *dx*, then integrate that from 0 to *l*. The variable *x* represents a position along the length *l*. As *t* can be expressed in terms of this position *x* as written in my initial post, we can express everything as:

$s = \int_0^l \frac{1}{\frac{t_{end} - t_{start}}{l} x + t_{start}} dx$

Then, the integrated value:

$s = \frac{ l \ln{( t_{start} l - t_{start} x + t_{end} x )} }{t_{end} - t_{start}} |_{0}^{l}$

Which, when evaluated, simplifies to:

$s = l ( \frac{ \ln{(t_{end} \, l)} - \ln{(t_{start} \, l)} }{ t_{end} - t_{start} } )$

And that, finally, is a formulaic expression of *s* for a given *l*, *t<sub>start</sub>*, and *t<sub>end</sub>*. Phew!

By the way, to test out this formula yourself, you can use a WolframAlpha query formatted similar to this, where L is length *l*, A is start tempo *t<sub>start</sub>*, and B is end tempo *t<sub>end</sub>*:

`Solve L*(ln(B*L) - ln(A*L))/(B-A) where A = 30, B = 150, L = 100`

Some properties such a formula should exhibit is that it always returns a positive number for a positive L because sample count is a physical quantity related to a play time, and flipping *t<sub>start</sub>* and *t<sub>end</sub>* should return the same value (as flipping start and end tempo shouldn't affect overall sample count).

Note that the formula is undefined at *t<sub>start</sub>* = *t<sub>end</sub>*, in this case the simpler formula ($s = \frac{l}{t}$) can be used instead as *t* is constant.